# SplitView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, splitview

Is there something similar to the SplitView from iOS for Android in Xamarin Forms?

I would like to use it especially for an application which has very much content to show. This would be perfect for Android Tablets, where I could show more of the content.

Comment: I don't think there is anything built in. I would use 2 content views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [MasterDetailPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/) what you're after?

> The Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage is a page that manages two related
>   pages of information – a master page that presents items, and a detail
>   page that presents details about items on the master page.

Comment: MasterDetailPage is something that I also had in mind, it is not quite the same, not so powerful, but it is better than nothing